# Reduce the space in between the UI controls

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angular-material

I am using angularjs v1 materials.

I have a simple configuration page which looks like this;

[image]

The html code is as below;

```
<md-card>
    <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">Room settings</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
    </md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
            <span>Room</span>
            <md-select ng-model="mode" placeholder="Mode1" class="md-no-underline">
                <md-option value="auto">Mode1</md-option>
                <md-option value="manual">Mode2</md-option>
            </md-select>
            <md-select ng-model="channel_number" placeholder="1" class="md-no-underline">
                <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
                <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
                <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </div>
    </md-card-content>
<md-card>
```

As you can see in the image, the space between the UI controls is too wide apart. I would like the gap to be much smaller. How should the html or/and css be changed to get this done?

Comment: you can change layout-align="start center" and then apply paddings on span, md-select and md-select , or you can also have flex on these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `layout-align` to `start center`, and add some margins to the elements inside the div.

```
...
<div layout="row" class="spaced-children" layout-align="start center">
...
```

CSS:

```
.spaced-children > * {
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/XhYvJFJJXGO0v20eWCBw?p=preview